# Can one walk to the Patriarchate of Peć?

Tags: walking, kosovo

The Patriarchate of Peć is right outside of the town of Peja/Pejë/Peć. [Lonely Planet](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/kosovo/peja-pec/attractions/patriarchate-of-pec/a/poi-sig/1252210/360677) says that you can get there by walking along "Lekë Dukagjini" while keeping the river on your left. I couldn't find this particular road on Google Maps, which instead [suggested](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Peja,+Pe%C4%87+District/Patriarchate+of+Pe%C4%87/@42.6630332,20.2641529,14z/am=t/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x1352fdc097e0cba1:0x2d9296d8cc0eba51!2m2!1d20.2887358!2d42.6592868!1m5!1m1!1s0x1352fc3bf9a9d553:0xde0f10ba1ff2cac6!2m2!1d20.2652977!2d42.6612563!5i1) walking along the M9 ("Mbretresha Teute").

Is walking along the M9 to visit the Patriarchate feasible? Is it still walkable now, in winter? (I heard it snowed recently.)

By "walkable" I mean:

- are there sidewalks? wide shoulders? grassy/non-street areas where one can walk and not have to worry about being run over?
- in winter, is the road/sidewalks plowed or passable?
- is walking along the M9 the best route or is there a more pedestrian-friendly street?

The distance is only about 2 km, so it's a question of what the road looks like rather than how far it is.

Comment: The patriarchate is off the M9 though, so getting the state of that road is kind of necessary since it can't really be avoided.

Comment: The road Mbretresha Teute runs along the river Lekë Dukagjini, keeping the river on the left. Where do you see a condradiction between Lonely Planet's suggestion and Google Maps?

Comment: The question is about the condition of this road and if it is passable on foot in winter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Lekë Dukagjini* road recommended by the Lonely Planet seems to be the M9 recommended by Google Maps. [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/node/3075195901#map=16/42.6583/20.2804) lists the *Lekë Dukagjini* street and it locates the M9 as a parallel street, more North. It appears that the more South road is more pedestrian-friendly (it is recommended by the Lonely Planet, by Google Maps and when looking at [the satellite view of the town of Pec], it looks less wide and therefore less busy). [Many comments on TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.fr/Attraction_Review-g737141-d3568798-Reviews-Patriarchate_of_Pec-Pec.html) mention a walk of 20 to 30 minutes to access the monastery, without difficulty.

Regarding the winter access, it seems like you will need extra caution. First, make sure you go there early enough since [the sun may set as early as 4pm](https://www.timeanddate.com/astronomy/kosovo/pristina). Then even though [some blog article](http://www.dont-complain.com/2014/02/11/travel-kosovo-patriarchate-of-pec/) of a visit in January/February 2014 shows no snow at the gate but some in a close town, [some comments on TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.fr/ShowUserReviews-g737141-d3568798-r239613265-Patriarchate_of_Pec-Pec.html) describe the road as trecherous for cars and requiring snow chains (therefore the snow might not be cleared fast). Finally, the main road seems quite busy on the satellite view, so if the snow is not cleared off of the sidewalks, then it might be quite dangerous.

In the end, it is likely possible to walk to the monastery, but in winter extra caution is required.